# Waiting for a HTTP request in middle of the main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, http, asynchronous

I have a queue and I have this consumer written in java for this queue. After consuming, we are executing an HTTP call to a downstream partner and this is a one-way asynchronous call. After executing this request, the downstream partner will send an HTTP request back to our system with the response for the initial asynchronous call. This response is needed for the same thread that we executed the initial asynchronous call. This means we need to expose an endpoint within the thread so the downstream system can call and send the response back. I would like to know how can I implement a requirement like this.

PS : We also can get the same response to a different web service and update a database row with the response. But I'm not sure how to stop the main thread and listen to the database row when the response is needed.

Hope you understood what I want with this requirement.

Comment: What is motivation for "This response is needed for the same thread"? Is it reuse of the Java object that sent the asynchronous request?

Answer (score 1):

My response based on some assumptions. (I didn't wait for you respond to my comment since I found the problem had some other interesting features anyhow.)

> the downstream partner will send an HTTP request back to our system

This necessitates that you have a listening port (ie, a server) running on this side. This server could be in the same JVM or a different one. But...

> This response is needed for the same thread

This is a little confusing because at a high level, reusing the thread programmatically itself is not usually our interest but reusing the object (no matter in which thread). To reuse threads, you may consider using `ExecutorService`. So, what you may try to do, I have tried to depict in this diagram.

[image]

Here are the steps:

1. "Queue Item Consumer" consumes item from the queue and sends the request to the downstream system.
2. This instance of the "Queue Item Consumer" is cached for handling the request from the downstream system.
3. There is a listener running at some port within the same JVM to which the downstream system sends its request.
4. The listener forwards this request to the "right" cached instance of "Queue Item Consumer" (you have to figure out a way for this based on your caching mechanism). May be some header has to be present in the request from the downstream system to identify the right handler on this side.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Just to add: I would also suggest serializing the object which is cached. This is because if the server goes down for some reason, then the object can be read from the serialized state (database) once the server comes back up. This would mean having some unique identifier in the data sent to Downstream system which the downstream can then send back. Downstream should also have a mechanism to resend the request if it gets back an error indicating the main application is down.